# How to login to website with some sort of AWS security using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm fairly new to developing but I'm having a problem logging into a website. The code I have currently types in the username, password and correctly clicks the log in button. However, the page simply refreshes, but doesn't actually log in. It is using some sort of AWS authentication, does anyone have any experience getting past this?

Code:
Here's the code I have right now:

```
from selenium import webdriver

username = "Username"
password = "Password"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("locationpath\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("website")
username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("signInFormUsername")
username_textbox.send_keys(username)
password_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("signInFormPassword")
password_textbox.send_keys(password)
login_button = driver.find_element_by_name("signInSubmitButton")
login_button.submit()
```

Comment: The website could have implemented Google invisible captcha.Only after token exchanges, the authentication flow might work. Can you look at the network console and find out the logic of the authentication?

Answer (score 0):

In RobotFramework I solved this issue by using Javascript to handle elements

```
Execute JavaScript  document.querySelectorAll('[id="signInFormUsername"]')[0].value = "${username}"
Execute JavaScript  document.querySelectorAll('[id="signInFormPassword"]')[0].value = "${password}"
Execute JavaScript  document.querySelectorAll('[name="signInSubmitButton"]')[0].click()
```